# Dynamically generating a generator function from a blob of text

Tags: python, generator

(Simplified from an excessively verbose question I posted earlier!)

Given a Python string containing valid Python code that contains a "yield" statement, how can I construct a generator that exec's that string?

For example, given the string:

```
code_string = """for x in range(0, 10):
    yield x
"""
```

I want to construct a generator f that executes code_string such that (in this particular example):

```
assert(list(f()) == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Note that code_string is ***arbitrary***, so this assertion is only valid for the example above. code_string can contain any valid python code that contains a yield statement.

Thanks!

Edit:

The first solution I thought of was to just munge "def f():" into the string and indent each line programmatically. However, that fails if code_string uses different indentation. I was hoping there were some little-known functools kung-fu that can construct a function from a blob of text.

Edit2:

I also tried an exec inside a function like so:

```
code = "for x in range(0, 10): yield x"
def f():
    exec code in globals(), locals()
```

This results in "SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function"

**Solved:** I stand corrected, indentation is relative, so this works:

```
code_string = """for x in range(0, 10):
    yield x
"""

exec "def f():\n" + [(" " + line) for line in code_string.split('\n')]) + "\n"
assert list(f()) == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Trust me, this is not the part of the problem that you want to solve.

Comment: :-) I appreciate the advice, but I like solving problems.

Comment: I deleted my answer, as I have no idea how to make it work (I think the exec() was only being called when the function produced by the closure was called, instead of when the producing function was called). I'd suggest looking at another way to solve this, as Ignacio suggested.

Comment: I think that what Ignacio was saying is that your problem is not what you think it is. If you get this to work, then you will have complicated spaghetti code that no one will understand. There is almost certainly a better way.

Comment: I understand that. I have to disagree with your assessment that I will have "complicated spaghetti code that no one will understand". This solution replaces a previous ad-hoc DSL that grew into hundreds of lines of pyparsing and regular expressions and IS complicated spaghetti code. I think we can all agree that Python is if anything an exceptionally clear and concise language, and I think it's ideal in this case as a DSL. Using the "yield" keyword to return results seems quite elegant to me. cheers!

Comment: Hey, if you used my answer, how about some checkmark love?  It's the least you can do after calling my baby ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you care what indentation is used within the function? Indentation is relative and does not have to be consistent. Tack "def f():\n" on the front, add a single space to each line in your function and exec it, and you're done.  This works just as well as your answer:

```
exec "def f():\n " + " \n".join(code_string.splitlines()) + "\n"
```

(Sorry to hear your pyparsing solution was too complicated.  It sounds like you were trying to recreate a full Python grammar just to add a feature or two to the language. In this case, instead of parsing the whole thing using parseString, you can just add some specialized syntax, define a pyparsing expression for *just that syntax*, write a parse action that creates Python code from it, and use transformString to search and replace the special syntax with the corresponding Python behavior.  Then you can exec or compile the whole transformed module, with just a little bit of pyparsing.)

Comment: So it is! I was under the (mistaken) impression that indentation had to be consistent throughout a compilation module. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
exec( """def f():
        for x in range(0, 10):
               yield x
""" )


for x in f():
    print x
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine if the code passed in uses 4-space indents. However, valid Python can use 2-space indents, too. I'm looking for a solution that works with arbitrary values for code_string.

Comment: I just thought of this... it's pretty easy to detect the indentation with a regular expression. max(min([indentations]), 4) will give a correct value.